# Ubuntu22.04 can't connect SQLServer. "SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:unable to get local issuer certificate]"

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, ssl

I want to run this on Ubuntu22.04(AzureVM).

```
<?php
    $dsn = 'sqlsrv:server=hogehoge';
    $user = 'user';
    $password = 'password';

    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    $sql = "select * from user";
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row) {
        echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['name'] . "<br>";
        }

    $dbh = null;
?>
```

But I got this error message.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed:unable to get local issuer certificate] in test.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/test/test.php(6): PDO->__construct()
#1 {main}
  thrown in test.php on line 6
```

What's happened? I searched for that error message but can't understand how to fix.
My local Windows does have not this problem. Maybe Ubuntu server is bad.

Thank you for your viewing.

Comment: Have you tried reading the release notes yet, [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228)? As in: **BREAKING CHANGE** - Default Encrypt to Yes/Mandatory.

Comment: Oh! I can understand! I need to add "TrustServerCertificate=1;" for $dsn! Thank you very much!!!